# Spring integration with ElasticSearch vs Elasticsearch Template

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-integration

Right now i´m developing an app that should connect with elacticsearch, however there are some different`s points of view to get solution, so i´m wondering witch could be a better use **Spring integration**(**int-http:outbound-gateway**) or **Spring-Data-ElasticSearch**(**ElasticsearchTemplate**), please feel free to write about it, thanks

Comment: without more details what do you want to achieve, what are your problems etc it is hard to advise. however you might want to check also spring data elasticsearch.

Comment: Well we have a lot of data(millions of rows) inside the db, so to handle the search we add some information to elastic, the process to extract that info from db and insert it into elastic could be done using spring-data-elasticsearch(ElasticsearchTemplate), but like those systems are isolated the integration pattern could be used, so my question its witch could be better.